# Go: как получить значения групп в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Официальную доку смотрел, но скудна она и таинственна.
Регулярка парсит апачевский лог:

```
`\"GET\s+/wp-content/uploads/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg))\sHTTP/1.\d\"\s+(\d\d\d)`
```

Соответственно, у нас тут три группы: (.+.(jpg|jpeg)), (jpg|jpeg) и (\d\d\d).
Каким методом получить массив совпадений по группам регулярки?

Comment: А что именно трудности вызвало? Там же примеры есть. Если они не понятны, посмотрите [здесь](https://github.com/StefanSchroeder/Golang-Regex-Tutorial/blob/master/01-chapter2.markdown) - вроде все разжевано

Comment: Ну как сказать... https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/ - даже параметры функций не описаны:

func (re *Regexp) FindAllString(s string, n int) []string
FindAllString is the 'All' version of FindString; it returns a slice of all successive matches of the expression, as defined by the 'All' description in the package comment. A return value of nil indicates no match.
К чему тут 'n', что оно означает?...

А за ссылку спасибо - пойду разбираться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо один из `Submatch` методов, например

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`"GET /wp-content/uploads/(.+\.jpe?g) HTTP/1.[01]"\s+(\d{3})`)
fmt.Printf("%#q\n", re.FindStringSubmatch(`"GET /wp-content/uploads/xxx.jpg HTTP/1.1" 123`))
fmt.Printf("%#q\n", re.FindStringSubmatch(`"GET /wp-content/uploads/yyy.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 123`))
```

Выводит

```
[`"GET /wp-content/uploads/xxx.jpg HTTP/1.1" 123` `xxx.jpg` `123`]
[`"GET /wp-content/uploads/yyy.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 123` `yyy.jpeg` `123`]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WtiSffLHrX